# How to prevent Telerik advertisement on Xamarin Forms application?

Tags: telerik, xamarin.forms

I am using Telerik charts for my Xamarin forms application.

Telerik advertisement is displayed for the page which includes Telerik charts. I can close this popup by the help of close button (X). However, I would like not to see this popup. How can I prevent this advertisement popup ?

[image: Advertisement popup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is already in the popup text. You should buy a commercial license.